# Python one tkinter program runs both from IDE and from '.py' but not second program

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a code for random Password generator GUI based on Python, program is running smoothly on any IDE but when i want to run directly from file ".py" just black screen flashed and programs goes down

I have run the same program from cmd line (windows 10) and programs runs fine as expected

for troubleshooting purpose i tried my old GUI base program which runs both on IDE and from '.py'

this program runs perfectly

```
import tkinter


def miles_to_km():
    miles = input_mile.get()
    km_convert = float(miles) * 1.609
    label_km_calc.config(text=f"{km_convert}")


window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title('Mile to Km Convertor')

window.config(padx=20, pady=20)

# label
label_1 = tkinter.Label(text='is equal to')
label_1.grid(row=1, column=0)

label_km_calc = tkinter.Label(text=0)
label_km_calc.grid(row=1, column=1)

label_mile = tkinter.Label(text='Miles')
label_mile.grid(row=0, column=2)

label_km = tkinter.Label(text='Km')
label_km.grid(row=1, column=2)

# Button
button = tkinter.Button(text='Calculate', command=miles_to_km)
button.grid(row=2, column=1)

# Entry
input_mile = tkinter.Entry(width=7)
input_mile.insert(0, '0.0')
input_mile.grid(row=0, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

[this is the program status when run from file '.py' directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ve45.png)

means there is no windows/OS setting problem

but my below code for the password Manager GUI program runs in IDE but not from '.py
note : I have omitted the other password related for code simplicity just GUI part

```
from tkinter import *

FONT_NAME = ("Courier", 10, 'normal')



# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #

window = Tk()

window.title('Password Manager')
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

# Canvas
canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
logo_image = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_image)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

# label
label_website = Label(text='Website:', font=FONT_NAME)
label_website.grid(row=1, column=0)

label_user = Label(text='Email/Username:', font=FONT_NAME)
label_user.grid(row=2, column=0)

label_password = Label(text='Password:', font=FONT_NAME)
label_password.grid(row=3, column=0)

# Entry
entry_website = Entry(width=33)
entry_website.grid(row=1, column=1)

entry_user = Entry(width=52)
entry_user.focus()
entry_user.insert(0, 'dummy@dummy.com')
entry_user.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)

entry_password = Entry(width=33)
entry_password.grid(row=3, column=1)

# Button
button_search = Button(text='Search', width=15)
button_search.grid(row=1, column=2)

button_Generate_p = Button(text='Generate Password')
button_Generate_p.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_add = Button(text='ADD', width=45)
button_add.grid(rows=4, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=10)


window.mainloop()
```

[this is the output of code when runs on IDE(tried multiple no problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6mLw.png)

program have also runs successfully if run from command prompt no error there

when i run my second program (password Manager GUU) from file '.py' just screen flashes and no error nothing

folks any ideaa

I have already tried to change import declaration

from tkinter import *

to

import tkinter

my python is python 3.10

Second attempt

Yes I troubleshoot once again if I comment out the PhotoImage part only
`logo_image = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')`
then it works fine and kept the canvas.create_image with image none it works fine. Why "PhotoImage" is creating problems anyone has feedback on that? This only creates problem of program runs directly from file ".py'

I am attaching the logo image[Logo_imahe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWJFU.png)

Comment: runs fine for me (though i had to remove the logo part)

Comment: The Password Manager GUI works fine when running from command prompt.

Comment: @AchilleG:
thanks for responding I tried your feedback and it's comes to that true only "PhotoImage" is seems to problem but why? Doesn't have problems from IDE or command line only for running directly from file I am attaching  the image [https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWJFU.png] , if you can try with image i will appreciate it because it will  narrow down the problem thanks again

Comment: @acw1668: yes it runs perfectly when runs from command prompt "Achille G" pointed out the ""PhotoImage" and problem narrow it down to this part of line. when i comment out this part of code ("PhotoImage") then programs also runs from file directly '.py'

Comment: Where is the image file located on disc relative to the python source files? Might be the IDE is running in another dir or making resources accessible that reside elsewhere. Just a guess, though. For the record, what IDE are you using and what does "from .py" mean? You double click it in Windows Explorer, is that it?

Comment: It worked for me. Are you eunning macox, unbuntu, pycharm, etc?

Comment: @Friedrich yes file located as relative same as python source file. code runs from Pycharm IDE, python IDE. code is able to run if I try run from windows command prompt codes runs perfectly good . problem occurs only if I try to run from source file "file.py" (double click) . then I troubleshoot by going commenting different block as suggested by "AchilleG" it turns out only one line is causing this behavior which is `logo_image = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')` . after commenting out this particular line problem is resolved but without the image in canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *"runs directly from file .py"* means that you double-click the python script in file explorer to execute it, then it may be that the current working directory is not the same as the script directory when the script is executed.

If it is the case, then you need to provide the correct path of the image instead of using *relative path*.  If the image is in the same directory of the script, then you can use the below code to provide the correct path of the image:

```py
import os
...
appdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
logo_image = PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(appdir,'logo.png'))
...
```

Comment: thanks this   `appdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` solve the problem. my current working directory is same as the script directory then why it didn't worked with simple 'relative path' . I tried two version first one is provided by you I even didn't give the path (__file__) just it took the abs path of the script and joined with file name. Your solution gave me option to try with hard coded abs path and it worked. I will stick with the solution provided by you as it is more flexible if script moved. Once again thanks